# insert html into template using AJAX with Python Flask

Tags: python, ajax, python-2.7, flask

I am trying to do something which I think is quite simple however I am a Flask newbie so I was hoping that someone could point me in the right direction.

I am making a Python Flask application for a user to manage their share portfolio.

I need to fetch share information from the yahoo finance server and render this on a page, however fetching this data can take a few seconds at which point the page is blank until the GET requests have been received at which point the page renders.

I want to load the page without the share data and then once the data has been received generate some HTML and insert this HTML into my page.

I have written a route that fetches all of the data and passes it to a Jinja2 template

```
@app.route('/sharedata')
def sharedata():
    js = share_data.getalljsonshares(current_user.username)
    io = StringIO()
    data= json.dumps(js, io)

    return render_template('sharedata.html', data=share_data.getalljsonshares(current_user.username))
```

I then use the following code in sharedata.html to render the HTML

```
{% if data %}

    <h2>You own the following shares</h2>

    {% for share in data %}

        <li>
            Ticker: {{share.symbol}}<br>
            Name: {{share.name}}<br>
            Quantity: {{share.quantity}} <br>
            Price: {{share['price']}}
        </li>

    {% endfor %}

        {% endif %}
```

Which results in the following page being rendered

```
You own the following shares

Ticker: AAPL
Name: APPLE inc
Quantity: 1 
Price: 102.71
```

I want to know how I can automatically insert this HTML into my template, I am sure that I need to use AJAX and JQuery but I am at a bit of a loss as to how I can directly insert HTML into my page once the GET requests have completed.
Thanks

Comment: Create div tag as container in main html/template and using jquery apply $('<container_div>').load('<url_to_share_template>') on load event

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use JavaScript. With jQuery this is a simple task.

In your `main.html` you have to write something like that:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
  $.on('ready', function() {
    $('#result').load('/sharedata')
  })
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it was trivial but I needed a pro!

Comment: @Daniel I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: $.on is not a function` I am using jquery version 3.1.1

Comment: I used  `$(document).ready(function(){...})`  instead of  $.on